# JSON Help regarding objects and stringify

Tags: json

I have a variable here which equates to

var4 = "{name: 'TestUser', data: [1.0, 0.8, 0.64]}"

```
series: [
     {
      name: 'TestUser',
      data: [1.0, 0.8, 0.64]
     }
],
```

I would like to find out how I can put var4 into my series instead of typing in the data. I have read up about JSON.stringify and parse but it doesn't seem to work here.

Comment: im trying to do something like this:

series: [
     {
      var4
     }
],

Comment: You can do that if you specify a key. Like so: ```arr = [{ 'key' : var4 }]``` now you can get the name like so: ```arr[0].key.name```. Please give my answer a vote up, or mark it as an answer if you found it helpful or it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.parse(str)` to turn a string into an object. Also define the JSON variable name as a string.

```
series = [
     {
      'name': 'TestUser',
      'data': [1.0, 0.8, 0.64]
     },
];

series.push(JSON.parse(var4));
```

Or maybe this is what you want:

```
myJsonObj = {
    'series': [
         {
          'name': 'TestUser',
          'data': [1.0, 0.8, 0.64]
         },
    ]
  }

myJsonObj.series.push(JSON.parse(var4));
```

Or this:

```
jsonObj = JSON.parse(var4);

myJsonObj = {
        'series': [
             {
              'name': jsonObj.name,
              'data': jsonObj.data
             },
        ]
      }
```